# Node.js MS Teams Mobile app cannot render O365 connector cards with Date Input

Tags: node.js, microsoft-teams

I'm diving in developing a Bot with MS Teams channel, my bot will be deployed both on PC and mobile Teams app. However, when I intended to create a card which allows users to pick a date time, then I have no idea with it.

I've searched a lot about Adaptive Cards and O365 Connector Cards, but only O365 Connector Card worked for me because Adaptive cards are only supporting in Dev Preview version at present.

This is my O365 Connector Card code:

```js
var actionCard = new teams.O365ConnectorCardActionCard(session)
      .name("Date Input")
      .inputs([
          new teams.O365ConnectorCardDateInput(session)
              .id("startTime")
              .title(util.cmdInputStartTime)
              .includeTime(true)
              .isRequired(true),
          new teams.O365ConnectorCardDateInput(session)
              .id("endTime")
              .title(util.cmdInputEndTime)
              .includeTime(true)
              .isRequired(true)
      ])
      .actions([
          new teams.O365ConnectorCardHttpPOST(session)
              .name("OK")
              .body(JSON.stringify({
                  startTime: '{{startTime.value}}',
                  endTime: '{{endTime.value}}'
              }))
      ]);
   
      var card = new teams.O365ConnectorCard(session)
          .potentialAction([
              actionCard
          ]);
      var msg = new teams.TeamsMessage(session)
          .attachments([card]);

      session.send(msg);
      
     // OK button process area
      var connector = app.connector;
      var o365CardActionHandler = function (event, query, callback) {
          var body = JSON.parse(query.body);
          callback(null, null, 200);
      };

      connector.onO365ConnectorCardAction(o365CardActionHandler);
```

Then I tested on mobile device but it got me a blank of reply like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zgKl.png)

I wondered is there something wrong when O365 Connector Card rendered on mobile device. Or else, is there any ways to help me solve the date time problem but Prompt.time?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long-standing issue that Office 365 Connector cards have not worked properly on Teams mobile clients. This is just one example.

Our mobile team is making a big push on this area this summer and should have Office 365 Connector cards (including "actionable messages" which is what this is) as well as the new Adaptive Cards standard working on both iOS and Android by mid to late summer 2018.

Comment: Very glad to hear that. My whole team is now pending until the Adaptive Cards officially supports for MS Teams as well as mobile version. Thank you so much! :)